# $_GET function doesn't see '+' or '%20' signs in the url

Tags: php, html, url, input, get

In a php file I am using this code:

```
header('Location: localhost/?room=ler&user='.urlencode('Indianu Talpa Iute'));
```

That sends me to a page where the url is: `localhost/?room=ler&user=Indianu+Talpa+Iute` and what I want is to insert these values in a form in the same page, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="user" value=<?php echo ''.$_GET['user'].'' ?> >
```

But it only displays `Indianu` in the textfield. Why? How can I fix this?

It works the same both for '+' and '%20' instead of space.

Comment: _Tip:_ When you want to echo a variable, you only need to do `echo $foo`. You don't need to put quotes around it like: `echo '' . $foo . ''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes around the value of `value` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo ''.$_GET['user'].'' ?>" >
```

And remember to at least use `htmlspecialchars()` to avoid XSS:

```
<input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['user']) ?>" >
```

PS. `$_GET` is not a function; it's a superglobal array.